# Is it possible to easily get all DNS/IP address that are classified for passthrough cluster

Tags: istio

I would like to whitelist only domains/services my services can reach out.
I see Istio showing `passthrough cluster` where services/domains it doesn't know
are routed to. I can find some by going through the `istio-proxy` logs on each pods
but it seems to be tedious and error-prone. Is there an easy way to list all the
entities that Istio has classified as passthrough cluster

Comment: Have you tried [that](https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/traffic-management/egress/egress-control/#controlled-access-to-external-services)?

Comment: @Jakub, I want to setup outboundTrafficPolicy to REGISTRY_ONLY as mentioned in your link. Before doing that I want to get the list of external services so that i can configure serviceEntries for them. Which is what I am trying to fugure out if there is an easy way in Istio to list all external services that are accessed

Comment: Which version of Kubernetes did you use and how did you set up the cluster? Did you use bare metal installation or some cloud provider? It is important to reproduce your problem.

Comment: GKE with kubernetes 1.20 and Istio 1.13.2

Comment: You are using old version of K8s, could you update it to supported one (min. 1.21)?

Comment: Could you please elaborate more on the version? what is the feature in 1.21? Thanks

Comment: [Here](https://endoflife.date/kubernetes) you can find dates of depreciation for Kubernetes. For changelog [look here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/master/CHANGELOG). If you can please upgrade your version to 1.23

Comment: @mik Ok I updated k8s to 1.23.3

Comment: And do you have still the same problem?

Comment: Yes. I still can't find an easy way to get DNS/IP address that are classified for passthrough clutser.

Comment: Did you try implement istio like [this](https://istiobyexample.dev/monitoring-egress-traffic/#:~:text=Option%202%20%2D%20REGISTRY_ONLY%2C%20no%20ServiceEntry)? As far as I know this is the best way